# Get Accounts with at least one attached object via SOQL

Tags: soql

We have an object that relates to Account (Services).  I'm trying to write a SOQL query that can give me accounts that have at least one active such object.  Those objects have a checkbox that is checked when inactive.  A single account can have dozens of these objects, inactive or not but I'm only interested in getting a list of Accounts that have at least one active.

I'm thinking something like

```
[SELECT id, account__r.id, account__r.name from service__c where cb_IsInactive = false]
```

But this returns me all active services by account.  Can I add a filter into this query that only gives me one line per account?  Some thing like COUNT() but of course not the same?

Edit: After hitting what I think are governor limits to my query I noticed the new (or semi-new) COUNT_DISTINCT aggregate query.  This returned me the total distinct number of accounts, and the rest was done by query all active services as csv, importing to Excel and using the filter functions there to eliminate duplicates.

EDIT2:  This here query worked for me, for anyone that has the same or similar problem

```
select COUNT_DISTINCT(Account__r.Id) from Service__c where chk_Inactive__c =false
```

Comment: select id, name from account where id in (select AccountId__c from service__c where cb_IsInative=false) would tht work ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply group by Account in your SOQL to query Service__c ? E.g.

```
SELECT Account__c, COUNT(Id) FROM Service__c 
WHERE cb_IsInactive__c = false
GROUP BY Account__c
HAVING Count(Id) > 0
```

Comment: This didn't work, ut I'd like to add what did.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the __c of the end of cb_IsInactive (fixed now). Other than that, it works. What error message did you get @akarnid?

Comment: I hit some governor limits I think.  If i do it directly then without limiting my query then I get "Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch".  And it only works correctly when I limit it to 5000 or less.  And with over 200.000 services that won't do.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: ah, of course 'the governor' :) no probs

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work but I'd like to add what did:

```
select COUNT_DISTINCT(Account__r.Id) from Service__c where chk_Inactive__c =false
```

This returned a count of all the relevant Accounts.

Comment: Please update your question with additional information, stackExchange does not function like a forum and the answer functionality is intended for solutions to the question.